Cómo consultar ordenes duplicados por campo de fecha creación(AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
Cordial saludo.
Tengo una inquietud resulta que tengo una tabla de ordenes sin embargo quiero revisar que no exista duplicidad de pedidos por campo de creacion(fech hora min) ya que necesito reportar si hay duplicidad de pedidos por ese lado.
Notas:
No pueden existir 2 ordenes en un mismo instante de tiempo ya que es imposible que coincidan, para un mismo cliente. Ya que en la app ingresan un único usuario por dispositivo, es como decir que 2 personas se pusieran de acuerdo para entrar un pedido en el mismo instante.
Ejemplo
la tabla orders tiene estos datos el id del cliente no lo ingreso pero si esto se requiere para hacer mas claro el ejemplo me avisan
CREATED             ORDER        DATE_MODIFIED
14/11/2024 16:33:22 PEDIDO12345 14/11/2024 16:35
14/11/2024 16:33:22 PEDIDO12346 14/11/2024 16:36
14/11/2024 16:35:25 PEDIDO12347 14/11/2024 16:37
14/11/2024 16:36:19 PEDIDO12348 14/11/2024 16:38
14/11/2024 16:37:33 PEDIDO12349 14/11/2024 16:39
14/11/2024 16:37:33 PEDIDO12350 14/11/2024 16:40
14/11/2024 16:39:10 PEDIDO12351 14/11/2024 16:41
14/11/2024 16:40:01 PEDIDO12352 14/11/2024 16:42
14/11/2024 16:41:12 PEDIDO12353 14/11/2024 16:43
14/11/2024 16:42:40 PEDIDO12354 14/11/2024 16:44

Intente con una sentencia
SELECT F.order,F.created
count(*)duplicados_ped_creacion, F.created FROM bd.orders F
group by F.created
having count(*)>1;

Pero no me encuentra nada los registros no son los que tienen ese campo de created duplicado mostraría entonces los pedidos con estas horas duplicadas ('16:37:33','16:37:33')
Muchas gracias a todos.

no deberia ser..  count(F.created)

@Bryro Es decir
SELECT F.order
count(F.created)duplicados_ped_creacion, FROM bd.orders F
group by F.created
having count(F.created)>1;

Con solamente fecha/hora:min no creo que puedas descartar duplicidad, 1 minuto es un periodo de tiempo demasiado largo para el proceso de guardado.
Deberías usar la ID,o datos únicos al momento de leer los datos.

Para encontrar pedidos duplicados por la fecha de creación en tu tabla orders, puedes usar esta consulta:
SELECT 
    created, 
    COUNT(*) AS duplicados_pedidos
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY 
    created
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;

Si lo que quieres es ver los detalles completos de los duplicados, usa esto te mostrará las órdenes que tienen la misma fecha exacta en el campo created. El o.* en SQL indica que se seleccionarán todas las columnas de la tabla o alias especificado
SELECT 
    o.* 
FROM 
    orders o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        created
    FROM 
        orders
    GROUP BY 
        created
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
) duplicados ON o.created = duplicados.created;

